# c# Как изменить UserAgent уже запущенного FirefoxDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
FirefoxDriverService ds0 = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
ds0.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
FirefoxOptions Opt0 = new FirefoxOptions();
Opt0.Profile = new FirefoxProfile(Maindir + "Main");
Opt0.Profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", UaF);
Wd = new FirefoxDriver(ds0, Opt0);
```

Так можно задать UserAgent перед запуском FirefoxDriver.
А как его изменить в уже запущенном?

Comment: Никак, насколько мне известно. И вы хотите странного.